# Random Number Generation problem in OMNeT++

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

I tried to generate two random integers `j` and `k` using the OMNET++ function `intrand()` but the first variable `j` takes a number out of the range. I had the same problem on OMNeT++6.0pre11 (installed on Ubuntu 18.04) and I thought that it was related to the software misbehavior. Then, I upgraded my OS to Ubuntu 20.04 and installed the OMNeT++6.0pre15 but I'm still experiencing the same issue.

Below are my piece of code and the output:

In my `.h`

```
public:

struct clusteringStruct {
   int CH_Index;
   map<int,double> Members;
   double FitnessValue;
   int trial = 0;
   double proba;
   double X[];
};

void generateNewSol(int n,clusteringStruct Cluster[],int z);
```

In my `.cc`

```
int D = 2;
clusteringStruct Cluster[5];

// Initialization...
for(t = 0; t < 5; ++t) {
   Cluster[t].X[0] = 0.5; // CH Residual Energy
   Cluster[t].X[1] = 500*sqrt(2); // Max distance
}

// Execution...
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   generateNewSol(i,Cluster,D);
}

void generateNewSol(int i,clusteringStruct Cluster[],int D) {
//  Randomly select the variable j that is to be changed
    int j  = intrand(D);

//  Randomly select the neighbour k and ensure that he is different from i
    int k = intrand(5);
    while(k == i) {
        k = intrand(5);
    }

    clusteringStruct sol = Cluster[i];
    for(int q = 0; q < D; q++) {
      sol.X[q] = Cluster[i].X[q];
    } 

EV_DEBUG <<" i = "<<i<<" || j = "<<j<<" || k = "<<k<<endl;
}
```

The Output of `j` and `k` variable is per the image below :

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show a proper [mre]. Also, which version of OMNetT++ are you using (there has been changes in both the API and bug-fixes regarding random number generation)?

Comment: Thanks @Some programmer dude. I edited my question. I'm currently using OMNeT++6.0pre15 on Ubuntu 20.04 . There's no changes regarding random number generation for this pre-release.

Comment: I just tested your example code but it is correctly working on my machine (6.0rc1).

Comment: 0k thanks @Rudi. So, my machine can be the cause...?

Comment: To me it looks more like the `j` you print is uninitialized. Are you sure you run the program you think you're running? Is it really built from the exact source you show us? Have you tried rebuilding the program from scratch (remove the executable and all object files and rebuild them from correct source)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, this portion of code is used as a function that I'm calling in my main program. Now, I copied and pasted it in my main program without calling it as a function and the value of the variable j is correct. Then, I placed it again in the function and called but it's the same misbehavior.

Comment: Then you're not showing us a *proper* [mre]. A perfect example should be possible to copy-paste by us, and without any changes or special flags/options when building, should be possible to build and replicate the behavior you ask about.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I updated the code to allow you to reproduce the error. I'm looking forward to your feedback

Comment: Please any suggestions???